# % pip install packages in a standalone python script

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I would like to install packages as I create a sparksession in a standalone python script (.py file) that will be uploaded and run in Databricks.

Something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

% pip install package-name
```

I don't use notebook so how can I configure this sparkSession so that it downloads and installs some external packages for me? I cannot install packages for the cluster since I do not have the rights.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html